# Java Wrapping an InputStream

Tags: java, inputstream

I need to repeatedly read from an InputStream. The stream is from reading some XML from a web service request. I'd like to keep the XML in memory so I may parse the stream multiple times, and ultimately trash the XML at some later time.
What can I wrap the InputStream in so I may access it multiple times?

Comment: I found this on SO: [this answer] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045632/bufferedreader-for-large-bytebuffer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're reading in a well-structured XML document, why not parse the document a single time using a DOM parser (for example, `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder`)?

This will provide you with an in-memory representation of the XML document in a structured format. If you use a parser like `DocumentBuilder`, you can subsequently fetch various parts of the structured data using the methods `Node` like `getElementsByTagName`, etc.

Comment: I want to use JAXB, and I'm having an issue with reading the XML multiple times

Comment: @bmw0128 you can load JAXB from DOM.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

// as often as desired.
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io) has a utility method that will read an input stream into a byte array (if you didn't want to write the function yourself) you could then wrap that in a ByteArrayInputStream i.e.

```
InputStream xmlInput = ...;
InputStream rereadableStream = 
    new ByteArrayInputStream(IOUtils.toByteArray(xmlInput));
```

and then use mark() / reset() or simply save the byte array and construct a new ByteArrayInputStream when needed.